# Flex CheckBox ItemRenderer Not Tied to Object?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have an Actionscript class we'll call `Person` to make the example easy. I want to have a `DataGrid` populated with `Person` objects that has columns displaying things like Name, Birthday, etc. All that is nice and simple, but I would also like to add a checkbox column to select certain people in the `DataGrid`. An example use case would be as follows:

1. Display all people.
2. User checks a box next to each person indicating they want some action taken on those selections.
3. Some action is taken on the user selections when the user clicks a button.

It seems like the common solution to this is to make a `Selected` property on each `Person` object, but that isn't really a good option for me. The `Person` object is used throughout the application, and it seems very unclean to have a `Selected` property which really isn't a concern of the `Person` class.

I like the type safety of having hard classes like `Person`, but I don't know how to solve this seemingly simple problem so I can loop through the objects and determine if the person is selected or not. Any tips on how to go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have your answer:

> It seems like the common solution to
>   this is to make a Selected property on
>   each Person object, but that isn't
>   really a good option for me. The
>   Person object is used throughout the
>   application, and it seems very unclean
>   to have a Selected property which
>   really isn't a concern of the Person
>   class.

The purpose of your "Person object" is to hold the state for one single entity (Person).  In this case, 'selected' is a perfectly valid value to add because it relates to the 'state' of that person in relation to your app.

I can think of other ways to do it; but they all add complexity which I feel is needless in this case.

Comment: I disagree. I think `Selected` is more of a UI concern than the state of a `Person` object (at least how I need it to be used). What if I needed one screen to display two DataGrid's, each filled with the same list of people but selecting for different reasons? One grid's `Selected` isn't the same as the other one.

Comment: "selected" is part of the object's UI state and I still think it's perfectly acceptable to store that value as part of the actual "UI-Persistent" object.  If I had multiple grids using the same data for different purposes, I would use multiple properties.  grid1Selected and grid2Selected.  That approach still seems simple to me.  I suppose you could work out some type of approach where you use an Object Mediator to maintain such values; but it seems like overkill to me.

Comment: It is an issue of separation of concerns. The object itself doesn't need to know if it is selected, only the UI does. Given that this business object is used in a large number of places, it would get very unwieldy very fast if every UI component that used it claimed it's own property in the business logic domain. It's a slippery slope that leads down the path of things like `Person.Width`. Sure it's easy to do, but I was hoping there would be a clean alternative that followed good coding practices.

Comment: @Ocelot20 I don't know enough about your object to be able to discern your issue w/ a separation of concerns.  I assumed "Person" was akin to a value object; being primarily a container of data.  If so, width makes no sense in that object.  However 'selected' is an obvious representation of it's state in the UI.  If you need to do processing on that object based on that 'state' then the object kind of needs to know somehow.  You could create "Dual" arrays, I suppose, one with the complete set and one with the selected set. It seems like a lot of extra coding overhead to me, though.